# How to pass the values into another code to execute a process in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have code for example script1 as follows:

1. Hello this is John
2. Hello this is Michael
3. Hello this is Andrew

This code is in such a way that it cannot be edited. But if we input 1 it will print `1. Hello this is John`, and so on..

I want to write a script in bash that it will automatically take inputs with out manually entering by the user.

I have tried like this
created a file `test.txt`:

```
1
2
3
```

And executed this way: `./script1 < test.txt`, but it keeps on iterating like infinite loop.

Can anyone try this. I just want 3 outputs.

Comment: Is `script1` reading from `stdin` or expecting a parameter in the command line? I'm guessing it doesn't read from `stdin`, otherwise the input redirection would have worked unless you are expecting to read 1 number at a time but input file has 3 numbers in a line. Does the script expect multiple parameters passed to it like `./script1 1 2 3`? Or does it only accept 1 parameter at a time?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

My reading of your question is that you are trying to accept input from standard in, but that you have immutable code which expects positional parameters. It would be helpful had you posted the relevant portions of the script that you can't modify.

So, I will assume you have something like this, which accepts positional parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

names=("" John Michael Andrew)

say_hello_by_id() {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        echo "Hello this is ${names[$1]}"
        shift
    done
}

echo "$(say_hello_by_id $@)"
```

Then, you would need to write a shim which reads values from stdin and passes them as arguments:

```
while read input; do
    ./existing.sh "$input"
done
```

Then do:

```
./shim.sh < inputs.txt
```

Comment: The OP's input file may contain a single line "1 2 3" but your code expects 1 number per line.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_user(){
while read -r values
do
if [ $values == $1 ]; then
echo "hello $1";
fi
done < $2
}
find_user $1 $2
```

**./find_user.sh jhon file.txt**

Comment: include explanation on how your code works or what it exactly does.